# Pull from a branch in Git

Tags: git, branch, pull

I am trying to pull contents from branch B to branch A that I am currently using. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. A pull is for when you want to get code from a remote repository into your local repository. For getting code from one branch into another, you may want merge, rebase, cherry-pick or some other command. I think you need to add more information to your question if you want a meaningful answer.

Comment: Do both branches already exist in both your local repository and the central one? Are you asking for the command `git merge`?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be creating a new branch off of branch `A`, then merge branch `B` into the new branch, `C`, and fix the diffs that you don't want.

Comment: I don't really think we have anywhere near enough information about the OP's situation to try to recommend workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Git has its way to do so: `pull` your branch `B` separatly, then `merge` it to your branch `A`:

```
$ git checkout branchB  
$ git pull origin branchB  
$ git checkout branchA  
$ git merge branchB
```

Then manage your conflict if there exist.